# Fool proof way to check Flat Panel - Monitor/ Screen/ TV for 4:4:4 Chrome Sub Sampling support?

Tags: display, external-display, lcd

Some Wiki & other information about it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:4:4
http://www.rtings.com/tv/learn/chroma-subsampling - Better explanation. (Quoted below)

```
      Subsampling   Visual impact
PC          4:4:4   Major
Movies      4:2:0   None
Video games 4:4:4   Minor
Sports      4:2:0   None
TV Shows    4:2:0   None
```

> Artifacts from chroma subsampling are at their most noticeable with text atop a flat color. The impact is far less visible in videos and photos. This matters when connecting your TV to a computer as you don't want your text to be blurry to the point of being unreadable.

As you can see, the lack of detail is clearly apparent in the bottom two rows. The text is all muddled together, and a lot of it is completely unreadable. While 4:2:2 fares better than 4:2:0, it still isn't what most would consider acceptable. While this pattern showcases an extreme case, similar side effects are visible in normal usage as well. It usually makes standard text look fuzzy and reduces its clarity. It's also important to note that subsampling on a PC requires using the YCbCr/YUV format as RGB does not support it.

[Samsung UN55JU7100 4k @ 60Hz under PC mode

Chroma 4:4:4](http://i.rtings.com/images/reviews/ju7100/ju7100-text-chroma-4k-60hz-pc-mode-large.jpg)
[image]

[Samsung UN55JU7100 4k @ 30Hz outside PC mode

Chroma 4:2:2](http://i.rtings.com/images/reviews/ju7100/ju7100-text-chroma-4k-30hz-large.jpg)
[image]

[Samsung UN55JU7100 4k @ 60Hz outside PC mode

Chroma 4:2:0](http://i.rtings.com/images/reviews/ju7100/ju7100-text-chroma-4k-60hz-large.jpg)
[image]

Forum **discussions** and community information and **some methods** that I found, but **not sure what is "the way" to do it**.

So anyone who has a sure shot way to check for it, please do guide correctly.

Comment: "The" way to do it is the way that works. Is there a reason the solutions and methods offered in the forums and elsewhere do not work?

Comment: @music2myear - Are you on a personal vendetta to bring up an old question to close? - They have not been reliable or uniform so me sharing my research and homework is not grounds for attack on your part. Read what I just made bold.

Comment: When you say check support, are you referring to looking up product specs or determining it by connecting to a computer and running a test?  Also, are you asking **if** it supports it, or how effectively it supports it (determined, for ex., by looking at test images)?  Are you looking for a method to query the system for internal information, or some sample content that you could display and evaluate by looking?  If you've already spent time researching this, how about summarizing what you've found so other don't need to duplicate what you've already done, or tell you what you already know?

Comment: There is no vendetta. I was going through a few of your previous posts because sometimes my curiosity takes me into people's post history, particularly when people allude to their own history in a comment thread. This post appears to link to some interesting information, and then appears to be asking us to provide opinions on which of the various linked methods is better, which just isn't a particularly on-topic sort of post. If you have a good question buried in there, it will be good if you edited the post to make that more apparent, improving the question and possibly attracting and answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 - You need to read the details of Chroma 4:4:4 more deeply as that's the verbiage used by forums & people. It has to do with how display panels Render at a fine grain level and you haven't bothered to try to understand what me and every person from such forums is talking about.

Comment: @music2myear I did not allude to my history, you did. You jumped from the voice control playback question to resurrect this one & again attack instead of look into homework & R&D done. I don't know what's the definitive way; as it's a niche subject limited to few forums/ threads and sites on the web. If you can decipher from the data what I was not able to garner then please post a definitive answer.

Comment: @AlexS I refer you to this comment https://superuser.com/questions/1342639/any-voice-control-for-locally-stored-media-music-videos-not-remote-cloud?noredirect=1#comment2009821_1342639 where you said "I'll share some examples of similar valid questions ... I've leveraged the same frame." I interpreted this as you saying you've asked similar questions and what drove my curiosity.

Comment: @music2myear - There's been several Q&As on SU where How do I do X was answered with a 1 or more "software/ programs" as part of that. So on SU one cannot or should not ask "I want a software that does this".. But how can I do that.. be it OS based, Script / automation based or App/ Prog based or a pipeline/ COMBINATION of them.  PS: I found Last Pass on such a Q&A posted by others on SU about secure password management